# Не полный перевод на английский в NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, локализация

Хотел поменять язык нетбинса с русского на английский. Поставил `--locale en` в параметрах запуска. Но перевело не всё. Видно на скриншоте. Можно ли поменять язык полностью без переустановки?

[image: Недоперевели]

upd. Навигатор перевелся после перезапуска, но всё же, если поискать то думаю можно таких багов, можно не мало найти